# Not displaying ether on Metamask on importing address from Ganache

Tags: metamask, ganache

I'm following [PetShop](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) tutorial, and everything works fine until Metamask came to the picture.

I've restored vault using mnemonic, added RPC URL`HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545`, it displaying Private Network at top, however ether is Zero, wheres in Ganache it's 100 ETH.

[image]
[image]

I've confirmed address twice, but no luck so far..Is there any work around?

Comment: try to lock metamask and open it again

Comment: Tried already, also tried with remove from Chrome and added it again, though no luck.

Comment: Check  the time sync.

Comment: @TahaBA: Sorry, didn't get you

Comment: Check the time on you PC .

Comment: @TahaBA: My PC time? it's `12:28PM 26-June-2018`.. but how does it matter?

Comment: Try resetting the account in MetaMask: settings > reset account

Comment: Thanks @Henk, tried with reset account, still issue is there..

Comment: @Henk: Funny but true!! `http` need to have in a lower letter :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems funny but you have to use `HTTP` in a lower letter. So use `http://127.0.0.1:7545` instead, and it'll start displaying Ether to your account.